# Is Braintree_Customer::create() returns credit card object on success

Tags: braintree

Is Braintree_Customer::create() returns credit card object in braintree on success?

It returns on failure in verification object.

**I want to know the best practice to access credit card object if it's present in response in case of success and failure of Braintree_Customer::create().**

Comment: Yes It returns in creditCards [an array of creditCards objects] and also in paymentMethods [an array of paymentMethods objects].

Now I want to know the best practice to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can access the newly created customer's payment method within the successful result object (Python);

My customer create call:

```
result = braintree.Customer.create({
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Smith',
    'company': 'Internet',
    'email': 'john@example.com',
    'payment_method_nonce':'fake-valid-nonce'
})
```

so

```
result.customer.payment_methods
```

will return an array containing the newly created payment method at index 0, which is essentially Braintree's [Credit Card Result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/), which contains all of the appropriate attributes for that credit card object.